# Reuse of a product for a different purpose

Tags: business-methods

Can I reuse a product for a different purpose?
Do I need the authorization from the product’s maker for a new and different purpose?

Comment: Do you want to patent a new use or just use the item in a way not originally intended?

Comment: We really need more information about what you want to do.